# how to pre-compile assets with Django-pipeline

Tags: django, assets, django-pipeline

I am using Modernizr for conditionally loading JS script. Now, locally this is working since the js are not compressed. In production, however, JS files are compressed to a file, so the modernizr condition won't work.

I looked into Rails they have "config.assets.precompile" that runs the conditional before compressing. Is there a way to do something like this in in Django.

Thanks